# Listen to disconnected nodes

Tags: android, wear-os

In a watch face configuration activity, i want to warn the user if its watch gets disconnected while he makes changes to the watch face configuration.

`Wearable.NodeApi.addListener` being deprecated, how can I listen to disconnected nodes in an activity ?

Using a `WearableListenerService` doesn't fit since I don't want to listen when the activity isn't open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CapabilityApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi) should work. There are two ways to get a list of connected nodes based on capability including a callback for changes:

1. Callback for Node changes: [CapabilityApi.CapabilityListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi.CapabilityListener)
2. Requesting current Nodes: [Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi.html#getCapability(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

**More details:**

Below is a snippet from Google's [RuntimePermissionsWear](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissionsWear) sample's [MainWearActivity.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissionsWear/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/runtimepermissions/MainWearActivity.java) file. In the **onConnected()** method, it sets up a listener for changes in the nodes and requests a list of current nodes (covers both scenarios).

Please note, this sample uses a custom capability (both for phone and wear), so you might change that part. If you are using a custom capability, it must be declared in the **wear.xml** file. ([Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissionsWear/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/values/wear.xml) is the one from the phone for the sample in case you are curious.)

```
    // Set up listeners for capability and message changes.
    Wearable.CapabilityApi.addCapabilityListener(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            this,
            Constants.CAPABILITY_PHONE_APP); // custom capability
    ...

    // Initial check of capabilities to find the phone.
    PendingResult<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult> pendingResult =
            Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    Constants.CAPABILITY_PHONE_APP, // custom capability
                    CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE);

    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult getCapabilityResult) {

            if (getCapabilityResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo = getCapabilityResult.getCapability();
                // Realistically, there is only on phone node with this capability, but you should check for multiple nodes to be safe (if wearable, many more possibilities)
                mPhoneNodeId = pickBestNodeId(capabilityInfo.getNodes());

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed CapabilityApi result: "
                        + getCapabilityResult.getStatus());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So it's clear for me : i have to create a custom capability that will just be used to identify the wearable ? And the listener will listen for changes about this capability which here will be used to target the wear ?

Comment: Yes, create the custom capability in your wear app and listen on your phone.

Since your phone app wants to check on the wear node being connected, your wear app creates the custom capability (XML or via code [my sample shows XML]), and you would listen for changes from within your phone's watch face configuration activity.

Comment: @codingjeremy: Can I find out the wear node being connected WITHOUT defining custom capability? That's what NodeListener used to do.

Comment: The official response is to use the CapabilityApi.

Awhile back, you could use WearableListenerService to listen to changes via the BIND_LISTENER intent filter in the AndroidManifest.xml for Node onConnect/onDisconnect but that was deprecated.

For awhile after that, you could still get node connects/disconnects by calling addListener() in NodeApi.NodeListener from an active Activity/Service, but that is deprecated too (doubt it still works).

For more info, check out official post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/deprecation-of-bindlistener.html